# How to use an AppSync public query in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, aws-appsync

I need to access an AppSync query without authentication.

I don't want to use API_KEY since it has an expiry date, so I would need to build a flow to update the API_KEY.

I think the best way to do this, would be to use AWS_IAM as the authentication method and allow unauthenticated identities from an Identity Pool.

I have done this successfully in VueJS with the Amplify SDK, but this time I want to do it in dart.

How can I make an AppSync HTTP request for an unauthenticated Identity in dart (Flutter)?

Comment: As per AppSync's [Security documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html), using `api-key` is recommended when a public api is needed.